# How to have custom darkmode colors with Tailwind

Tags: css, user-interface, tailwind-css

I am trying to set up Tailwind for my project (this is my first time using it), but can't figure out how I'm supposed to define colors for dark and light themes; is there a way to do something like this:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@dark
{
   --red: #FFC8C8;
}
@light
{
   --red: #F00000;
}
```

```js
module.exports = {
   darkMode: 'class',
   theme: {
      extend: {
         'red': 'var(--red)',
      }
   }
};
```

That is a hypothetical representation of what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately none of the tutorials I've found for Tailwind explain how to do anything like that. Is there a way to customize a darkmode palette with Tailwind? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to give the custom class name and give it light and dark property in css file.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  darkMode: "media",
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        red: {
          dark: "#FFC8C8",
          light: "#F00000",
        },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  .redcolor {
      @apply text-red-light dark:text-red-dark;
}
```

**apply this way.**

```
 <div className=" p-4 redcolor">Hello</div>
```

Light Mode:
[image]

Dark Mode:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```js
// tailwind.config.js

// only if you want to use (!)RGB values
function withOpacityValue(variable) {
  return ({ opacityValue }) => {
    if (opacityValue === undefined) {
      return `rgb(var(${variable}))`
    }
    return `rgb(var(${variable}) / ${opacityValue})`
  }
}

module.exports = {
  ...
  colors: {
    gray: {
      50: withOpacityValue('--gray-50'),
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

In you tailwind.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities; 

:root {
  --gray-50: 192 178 131;
}

.dark {
  --gray-50: 220 208 192;
}
```

Please note `.dark` class is the name of your theme. `:root` is going to be your default theme. So, besides `.dark` you can define other themes.

One of the downsides (in my opinion) that I've noticed is that the themes will not switch automatically; the user will need to refresh the page.

Reference: [Tailwind -> Colors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors)